# Jquery Grid Edit,Delete in mvc4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to free Jquery grid with enabled edit,delete and paging in mvc application
 could you please give demo

Comment: In order to get a useful response, I would advise you to extend your question. What exactly do you need, and what options have you already considered yourself? Why are they not sufficient? Why do you mention Telerik? It's pretty hard to understand what you want, and why you're asking for it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check http://www.jqwidgets.com/
They have a gridview component that is free to use under certain conditions:
http://www.jqwidgets.com/license/

Edit: You can find a demo here: http://jquerygridview.com/